# Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error: no such field Return to home page

Tags: profile, error

I have created profile forms, using custom fields, which open up perfectly in create mode but when I test the forms I get this error once I hit save:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error: no
>   such field Return to home page.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Here is a link to one of the forms in question: http://skillsguru.web.za/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/create&gid=21&reset=1

The detailed debugging report is [here](http://skillsguru.web.za/blog/2017/01/11/debug/).

Comment: may be easier to help you if you can add a quick example on one of the demo sites.

Comment: note that Demo sites get rebuilt every 24 hours - hopefully your efforts will last long enough for someone to take a look before it gets wiped

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could edit your question to include the version of CiviCRM and the CMS you are using (e.g. WordPress, Drupal or Joomla).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error in the debug message, the problem field is this one: `civicrm_value_developing_an_accredited_course_5.provide_instructions_on_any_furt_119`

I can't find it now, but there was a bug report recently that discussed problems with very long custom field names.  Please find your custom field with an ID of 119 and see if the form works when it's removed (or at least see if the MySQL error changes).  Consider recreating those fields with shorter names - you can always display them with the longer "names" in the profile's field label.